# How to find and replace a part of a value in json file in python by taking a result as an argument?

Tags: python, json

The output of the function I run is in format int. I should replace the number in json file

```
                        "x":{..},
                        "y":{..},
                        "z":{
                           "zz":{
                             "test1": "2010-11",
                             "test2": "somestring",
                         },
```

how do i search and replace the test1 part with the output of the result i get?

Answer (score 1):

What the question is asking for is a 5 step process:

1. create a (properly formed) dict.
2. create a function that returns something.
3. call the function.
4. change the value of a specific key.
5. write the new json string.

This is code that will do such:

```py
import json

def some_function():
    return 'hello world'

# create a dict
d =  {  "x":{'a':'b'},
        "y":{'a':'b'},
        "z":{"zz":{
                    "test1": "2010-11",
                    "test2": "somestring",
                }
        }
}

# call the function
x = some_function()

# change value of a specific key
d['z']['zz']['test1'] = x


# write the new json
j = json.dumps(d, indent=4)
print(j)
```

Here is the result:

```
{
    "x": {
        "a": "b"
    },
    "y": {
        "a": "b"
    },
    "z": {
        "zz": {
            "test1": "hello world",
            "test2": "somestring"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @shinoda,  you just have to set `d['z']['zz']['test1'] = (whatever the function returns)` to be the value of the result...

Comment: I have added two extra steps to include a generic function and return the value to the json.  So the question has a complete 5 step process now.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @D.L. is correct, so to assign the function result to the dictionary, just assign it like a normal string or variable value.

```
# pretend I read data from a file, now I have a dictionary
data = {
    "x": {},
    "y": {},
    "z": {
        "zz": {
            "test1": "2010-11",
            "test2": "somestring",
        },
    },
}

# function returns the val in 'test1' by just running a string replace
# I don't know what your function does, but the 
# point is the return value: newval - which is then used directly where you
# called it
def get_results(val):
    newval = ''
    newval = val.replace('-11', '-10')
    return newval


for k,v in data.items():
    if k == 'z':
        for k2, v2 in data[k].items():
            if 'test1' in data[k][k2].keys():
                # print(data[k][k2]['test1'])
                curval = data[k][k2]['test1']
                newval = get_results(curval)  
                data[k][k2]['test1'] = newval  # the return value
```

You could use the much cleaner code from @D.L. and then assign the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand the question, you should be able to use the keys in this dictionary/json object:
obj['z']['zz']['test1'] = "2010-10"

obj pertains to the variable name of the object.

Comment: Yes but how do i pass the function results directly to this json file instead of assigning it manually. because the results may change

Comment: Still not completely understanding scenario, but if you are reading the json file in, pass it to your function, have the function run through it key by key and then rewrite the file out as json, but updated.  I think it is a read, change, write setup.  But not sure. If you post the json file and the function, perhaps I can come up with more help.   I am also learning.

Comment: let me play with this a bit